# Can I use Autonomous JSON Database for storing and accessing large amount of XML data?

Tags: oracle, oracle-autonomous-db

I need to store and process large amount of XML data with high performance. Can I use Autonomous JSON database for this use case?

Comment: *Can I use a Russian-English dictionary to translate my question from Portuguese to English?* \ Easy: **no**.

Answer (score 0):

Autonomous JSON Database (AJD) is targeted for users using JSON data and JSON-friendly NoSQL APIs and has a 20GB limit on storing and accessing non-JSON data. You can read more about AJD in [this blog post](https://blogs.oracle.com/jsondb/autonomous-json-database).

For transactional XML data, you can use Autonomous Transaction Processing (ATP).